# Registering and consuming single instance with various dependencies with Autofac in ASP.NET application

Tags: asp.net, dependency-injection, autofac

I want to have a single instance of WorkerContainer class that injects various worker implementations. I want to get this instance in Global.asax and start workers.

```
public class WorkerContainer
{
    IWorker[] _workers;
    public WorkerContainer(IWorker[] workers)//DI
    {
        _workers = workers;
    }
    public void StartWorkers()
    {
        foreach(IWorker w in _workers)
        {
            w.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Each worker implementation can inject some service registered with "InstancePerRequest". This is part of my IoCConfig code:

```
//some service that I use in WebApi controllers
// as well as in WatchersWorker
builder.RegisterType<WatcherService>()
       .AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
builder.RegisterType<WatchersWorker>()
       .As<IWorker>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();//one worker implementation
builder.RegisterType<WorkerContainer>().SingleInstance();
```

Then I try to get that single instance. I cannot find Resolve method from container, only ResolveComponent that I don't know how to use.

```
WorkerContainer workerContainer = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<WorkerContainer>();
```

With this configuration I get this error:

"*No scope with a Tag matching 'AutofacWebRequest' is visible from the scope in which the instance was requested. This generally indicates that a component registered as per-HTTP request is being requested by a SingleInstance() component (or a similar scenario.) Under the web integration always request dependencies from the DependencyResolver.Current or ILifetimeScopeProvider.RequestLifetime, never from the container itself.'"*

I know this configuration is not good, and will not work, but until I transfer some of my features in some Windows service and set up DI the right way there, is there a way to accomplish this in my ASP.NET application?